# Verify.js - Validation using regular expressions

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm using the Verify.js library (http://verifyjs.com/).  It seems to be exactly what I need to do client side validation.

However, I'm having trouble getting it to work with my regular expressions I'm writing.  It seems whenever I try a lookahead, the form is always allowed to be submitted and the regular expression is not evaluated (maybe it's not compiling)?

I believe my regular expression is correct.  I'm trying to verify the user input an integer or a decimal.

```
<form>Type abc
<input required type="text" data-validate="regex(^abc$)" />Type integer/decimal
<input required type="text" data-validate="regex(^[0-9]+([\,\.][0-9]+)?$)" />
<input type="submit" />
```

Here's a fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/ms4pg776/1/

Comment: Why not use the built in [decimal rule](http://verifyjs.com/#included-rules)?: https://jsfiddle.net/82Lsnytv/

Comment: @JasonCust Because the the user is allowed to define regular expressions for forms.  I need to have a method that allows an arbitrary regex to be used.  However, for this example, you are right, decimal rule would work!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this by adding a rule to the $.verify variable.

```
$.verify.addRules({
    isIntegerOrDouble: {
        regex: /^[0-9]+([\\.][0-9]+)?$/,
        message: "Please enter an integer or a decimal number."
    }
});
```

Then in the HTML:

```
<input required data-validate="isIntegerOrDouble" type="text"/>
```

Hope it helps someone!